# Rendering the screen too slow in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, internet-explorer

We have a screen that displays around 800 lines on the grid and when we render through Internet Explorer it gets very slow and with delay in clicks, however if we render in Chrome it gets great response time. Could someone help me on this issue?

I removed the concept of partialView on this screen and I am doing everything only in one View, however it is still very bad when working with IE. We must work on IE.

Comment: I am assuming you have a table in there? Tables on IE are very slow because at each addition of an element from the DOM render, a calculation runs to determine the size of each cell in the table.

Comment: Right, we work with two tables on the screen.

Comment: Setting default sizes could help by removing the need to automatically determine the size. It would at the very least serve as a test to see if that was the issue.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: Emphasizing that we force the application to use the But recent rendering with the following tag:`<meta content=""IE=edge,chrome=1"" http-equiv=""X-UA-Compatible"">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Performance analysis in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imFRD.png)

We did a performance report and commented on the. js files, whose has a longer runtime. We did not get improvement over the screen crash in the rendering of the page.

Comment: I solved my problem. IE does not interpret some characters in the CSS other than Chrome for example.